# dpkg interupted error when update linux kernel (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: apt, kernel, updates, dpkg

it began when i run software updater to update what it told me to update
in the process.. i got powerdown in my area...

when it back again... i got eror: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct 
i run dpkg --configure -a ...the problem stick..got eror after restart.. 
then i press F for automatic fix

after login the eror "dpkg was interupted still doesnt fix.."
still can't install anything...googling for answer..

found remove anything inside /var/lib/dpkg/updates
run apt-get update...after that apt-get install is running again

but after installing apt...it continue the update from previous..than error again..it looks like this..

```
Setting up libtinfo-dev:i386 (5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libncurses5-dev:i386 (5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libssl-doc (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.22) ...
Setting up zlib1g-dev:i386 (1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libssl-dev:i386 (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.22) ...
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic (4.4.0-63.84~14.04.2) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-63-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-63-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-63-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-63-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-63-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-63-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-63-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-63-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-63-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-63-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-63-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-63-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-63-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-59-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft: 49: /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft: cannot create /tmp/os-prober.pmV1Np/os-prober.tmp: Read-only file system
mv: cannot stat ‘/tmp/os-prober.pmV1Np/os-prober.tmp’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/os-prober/mount’: Read-only file system
/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft: 49: /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft: cannot create /tmp/os-prober.pmV1Np/os-prober.tmp: Read-only file system
mv: cannot stat ‘/tmp/os-prober.pmV1Np/os-prober.tmp’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/os-prober/mount’: Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/os-prober/mount’: Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/os-prober/mount’: Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/os-prober/mount’: Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/os-prober.pmV1Np/swaps-map’: Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/os-prober.pmV1Np/mounted-map’: Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/os-prober.pmV1Np/raided-map’: Read-only file system
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
cat: write error: Read-only file system
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-xenial:
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-63 (4.4.0-63.84~14.04.2) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to flush updated status of `linux-headers-4.4.0-63': Read-only file system
touch: cannot touch ‘/var/lib/update-notifier/dpkg-run-stamp’: Read-only file system
sh: 1: cannot create /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available: Read-only file system
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Post-Invoke 'if [ -d /var/lib/update-notifier ]; then touch /var/lib/update-notifier/dpkg-run-stamp; fi; if [ -e /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available ]; then echo > /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available; fi '
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

any help??

this is dmesg output

```
[  330.022171] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  330.022177] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor] 
[  330.022182] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[  330.022188] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 8a d5 b5 00 00 01 00
[  330.022192] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 9098677
[  330.022198] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 6024629, async page read
[  330.022217] ata1: EH complete
[  333.860534] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  333.860542] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[  333.860548] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  333.860557] ata1.00: cmd 60/01:c0:b5:d5:8a/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq 512 in
[  333.860557]          res 41/40:01:b5:d5:8a/00:00:00:00:00/60 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[  333.860562] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  333.860565] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[  333.862123] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[  333.862147] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  333.862154] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor] 
[  333.862160] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[  333.862166] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 8a d5 b5 00 00 01 00
[  333.862170] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 9098677
[  333.862176] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 6024629, async page read
[  333.862198] ata1: EH complete
[  337.700536] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x20 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  337.700544] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[  337.700550] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  337.700559] ata1.00: cmd 60/01:28:b5:d5:8a/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq 512 in
[  337.700559]          res 41/40:01:b5:d5:8a/00:00:00:00:00/60 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[  337.700564] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  337.700567] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[  337.702137] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[  337.702160] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  337.702166] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor] 
[  337.702172] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[  337.702178] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 8a d5 b5 00 00 01 00
[  337.702183] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 9098677
[  337.702189] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 6024629, async page read
[  337.702213] ata1: EH complete
[  341.544533] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x20000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  341.544541] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[  341.544548] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  341.544558] ata1.00: cmd 60/01:88:b5:d5:8a/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq 512 in
[  341.544558]          res 41/40:01:b5:d5:8a/00:00:00:00:00/60 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[  341.544563] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  341.544566] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[  341.546121] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[  341.546147] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  341.546154] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor] 
[  341.546159] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[  341.546165] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 8a d5 b5 00 00 01 00
[  341.546169] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 9098677
[  341.546176] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 6024629, async page read
[  341.546193] ata1: EH complete
[  343.728567] EXT4-fs error (device sda8): ext4_lookup:1576: inode #1068543: comm rm: 'mozstd-trackwhite-digest256.cache' linked to parent dir
[  343.748609] EXT4-fs error (device sda8): ext4_lookup:1583: inode #1068543: comm rm: deleted inode referenced: 1068568
[  343.757650] EXT4-fs error (device sda8): ext4_lookup:1583: inode #1068543: comm rm: deleted inode referenced: 1071323
[  343.768635] EXT4-fs error (device sda8): ext4_lookup:1583: inode #1068543: comm rm: deleted inode referenced: 1071324
[  343.779695] EXT4-fs error (device sda8): ext4_lookup:1583: inode #1068543: comm rm: deleted inode referenced: 1071325
[  343.790797] EXT4-fs error (device sda8): ext4_lookup:1583: inode #1068543: comm rm: deleted inode referenced: 1071326
[  343.801860] EXT4-fs error (device sda8): ext4_lookup:1583: inode #1068543: comm rm: deleted inode referenced: 1071327
[  343.813013] EXT4-fs error (device sda8): ext4_lookup:1583: inode #1068543: comm rm: deleted inode referenced: 1071328
[  343.824112] EXT4-fs error (device sda8): ext4_lookup:1583: inode #1068543: comm rm: deleted inode referenced: 1071329
[  858.968611] perf interrupt took too long (5001 > 5000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root filesystem got remounted read-only in the middle of dpkg running. This is likely because of filesystem corruption. Check the output of `dmesg` to see if this is what happened.

Edit: now that you posted your dmesg, it looks like your hard drive is dying. Note all of the entries about unrecovered read errors. If I were you, I'd back up my important data immediately and replace the hard drive.

Comment: so how to repair it??

Comment: but i wonder...the eror in sda2 which is windows partition, my ubuntu is in sda8 and swap in sda9